# Unable to create new permission set for Solidus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've started on creating multi vendor permissions for Solidus.
I used one of the other permission_sets as a starting point, but I'm missing one crucial thing.

As you can see, my test fails:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/spree/permission_sets/multi_vendor_spec.rb


multi_vendor_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': 
uninitialized constant Spree::PermissionSets::MultiVendor (NameError)


        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
        from gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
        from bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Can you see why Spree::PermissionSets::MultiVendor is reported uninitialized?

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to add
`require 'spree/permission_sets/multi_vendor'` to  **spree/permission_sets.rb**